# Return a modfied object from a promise to async() block

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, web-worker

I start a webworker (computing a hit into a game) into a promise and I would like to get back the results (always an array) once webworker has finished its computations.

I tried, at the end of promise, to return the object after the `then(`and to do in main thread :

```
(async () => {
    // Wait computeHit function
    await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');
```

But it seems when computation done by `computeHit` is high, there are conflicts between `return HitCurrent` from `promise` and the `HitCurrent = await` option into `(async () =>`block.

It is clearer on the code below :

the background consists of :

1) the using of webworker

2) the using of promise

3) the async/await keywords

Promise block :

```
function computeHit(HitCurrent, mode) {

if (mode == 'computer') {

let HitTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent));

return new Promise( resolve => {
       // Creation of webworker
       firstWorker = new Worker(workerScript);
       firstWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
       resolve(event.data);
}

// Post current copy of HitCurrent, i.e HitCurrent
firstWorker.postMessage([HitTemp, HitTemp.playerCurrent, maxNodes]);
}).then(({result}) => {

// Get back game board of webworker
HitTemp = result.HitResult;

// Get back suggested hit computed by webworker
[a,b] = HitTemp.coordPlayable;

// Drawing all lines from suggested hit (in 8 directions)
// HERE, we modify HitCurrent attributes (like array)
for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
  exploreHitLine(HitCurrent, a, b, k, 'drawing');
}

// Remove playable hits
cleanHits('playable', HitCurrent);

// Display current game
displayCurrentHit(HitCurrent);

// Return object HitCurrent
return HitCurrent;
})}
}
```

Async block waiting for promise above is :

```
(async () => {
      // Wait computeHit function and update HitCurrent when promise is done
      HitCurrent = await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');
      // Reset, switch and update
      resetSwitchUpdate(HitCurrent, false);
})();
```

I would like to get the updated `HitCurrent` object (modified as I said into `exploreHitLine(HitCurrent, a, b, k, 'drawing');`) and this, once webworker has received its results (a value and an object HitResult).

I don't know how to make the behavior of `await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');`and the return that I apply the end of `Promise`, i.e :

`return HitCurrent;`

What is the correction solution ? :

1) doing :

`(async () => {
          // Wait computeHit function and update HitCurrent when promise is done
          await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');`

with into `Promise` :

`return HitCurrent;`

2) doing :

`(async () => {
          // Wait computeHit function and update HitCurrent when promise is done
          Object = await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');`

with into `Promise` :

`return HitCurrent;`

---

for 2) case, if this is the solution, how can I get back the `Hitcurrent` object from local variable `Object` ? **I saw that result may be a wrapper.**

**I think an important point is that returning a promise is different from returning an Object like `HitCurrent`, isn't it ?**

For the moment, for light computation into webworker, solution given in the code section of this post works fine but as soon as I have high computation for webworker, the code terminates itself the game, without no more interactions for the user hit (that I do with mouse click on game board).

So, I would like to get advices to get back the object `HitCurrent` from  `Promise` block in all cases, for light and high computation of webworker.

Comment: Do you mind to post the whole function for this part `Async Function waiting for promise above :`?

Comment: @Uma the async Function is actually the block `(async () => {
      // Wait computeHit function and update HitCurrent when promise is done
      HitCurrent = await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');
      // Reset, switch and update
      resetSwitchUpdate(HitCurrent, false);
})();`

Comment: @Uma . My main issue is that I don't know the concurrency or priority between the return of promise (`return new Promise`) and the `return HitCurrent` into then of `then`of promise.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*there are conflicts*"? How often are you calling `computeHit`? If there are multiple conflicting calls, make sure not to use global variables.

Comment: @Bergi . You can check the game on the link I provided into my **UPDATE 1** : you will see that everything is working fine for a depth between 1 and 3 but for depth = 4, I am losing the hit of user (with mouse click), i.e the game terminates itself (black cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after looking at the demo I think I see a reason why it might be breaking..

You have `currentGame` function with multiple cases for the game mode (user / computer, etc), and for computer mode you are calling that function that returns promise. The problem is that promise is wrapped in immediately invoked function which means that the code below it doesn't wait and keeps executing.

Just to illustrate what I mean, here's an example for you:

```
var testPriomise = () => new Promise(resolve => { resolve(2)})

console.log('1');
(async() => {
    var result = await testPriomise();
    console.log(result)
})()

console.log('Look! I fire before 2!', 3)
```

If you run it in console you'll notice that it logs 1, 3 and only then 2.
I hope that you see where I'm going with it:)

Make these few changes:
Instead of

```
// Main game function : started with white player
function currentGame(HitCurrent) {
```

do

```
// Main game function : started with white player
async function currentGame(HitCurrent) {
```

And for your computer mode case do this :

```
// Play computer hit
   else {
    // First option : Wait computeHit function
    await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');

    // Reset, switch and update
    resetSwitchUpdate(HitCurrent, false);
   }
```

This way you ensure that the `resetSwitchUpdate` has updated `HitCurrent` object.

I hope this will fix it!

Comment: Sorry but in your suggested code, you have not included `postMessage` into  `onmessage`, have you ? Same thing for `close()` function.

Comment: You can check the game on the link I provided into my **UPDATE 1** : you will see that everything is working fine for a depth between 1 and 3 but for depth = 4, I am losing the hit of user (with mouse click), i.e the game terminates itself (black cases).

Comment: Updated the answer, looking at demo really helps

Comment: thanks a lot. Why my first solution was not working ? I thought that block `(async () => {
      // Wait computeHit function and update HitCurrent when promise is done
      await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');
      // Reset, switch and update
      resetSwitchUpdate(HitCurrent, false);
})();` would allow to wait for the execution of `computerHit` function. What you did is to remove the wrapper `{async () => ... }()` and put `async`on `currentGame` function ? what does it change towards my initial solution ? regards

Comment: so what happens when you call promise inside of `{async () => ... }()`, is that the code outside of that function does not know that it needs to wait for it to finish. the `await` needs to be on the same level where  you want the code to take precedence. So in this case `{async () =>   await computeHIt(); // HitCurrent below this line inside of this anonymous scope is updated... }()   // code below already executed and kept using not updated yet object which will be updated at some point later `

Comment: Yes you could put  `resetSwitchUpdate(HitCurrent, false)`  in the same anonymous function but if you want others functions that will be called after `currentGame` wait for it to finish you would need to make the change I suggested